# How to get boolean result of a string in c# for using in if statement

Tags: c#

I have a string such as "4 == 5 || 3 == 3 || 2 == 1" in c#.
How can I get this string to if statement,
actually i want to build if statement programmatically.

Comment: You need a expression-parser? That´s a quite big-task which is far more complex than you imagine. However you have to show some own affords to get answers here. In particular have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Anyway you should have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx. Expression-trees are a way of dynamically create expressions during runtime-

Comment: Thanx,actually i dont want an expression-parser,i am sure that my string has true format, i need just checking it in my program

Comment: I got it,thank you

Comment: You´re welcome to post your solution here so that further readers having a similar question might get an idea as well.

Comment: sure,i think i have to write my own function,ill send it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple implementation that can be extended. This is all based on your statement that you are sure of the format. You can extend this add multiple operators:

```
private static bool? EvaluateBooleanExpression(string expression)
{
    var stack = new Stack<string>();
    var elements = expression.Split(new string[] { " " },
                                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    bool? expressionResult = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
    {
        string item = elements[i];
        bool isLast = i == elements.Length - 1;

        if (item == "||" || item == "&&" || isLast)
        {
            if (isLast)
                stack.Push(item);

            int v2 = Int32.Parse(stack.Pop());
            string op = stack.Pop();
            int v1 = Int32.Parse(stack.Pop());
            bool localResult = false;
            if (op == "==")
                localResult = v1 == v2;
            else if (op == "!=")
                localResult = v1 != v2;

            if (stack.Count > 0 && (stack.Peek() == "||" || stack.Peek() == "&&"))
                item = stack.Pop();

            if (expressionResult == null)
                expressionResult = localResult;
            else if (item == "||")
            {
                expressionResult = expressionResult.Value || localResult;
                // no need to check further if one result is true
                if (expressionResult.Value)
                    break;
            }
            else if (item == "&&")
            {
                expressionResult = expressionResult.Value && localResult;
            }

            if (!isLast)
                stack.Push(item);
        }
        else
        {

            stack.Push(item);
        }
    }

    return expressionResult;
}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string expression1 = "4 == 5 || 3 == 6 || 2 == 1";
    string expression2 = "4 == 4 && 5 == 5 && 7 == 7";
    string expression3 = "4 == 4 || 5 == 5 && 3 == 7";

    Console.WriteLine(expression1 + " Evaluates to: " + EvaluateBooleanExpression(expression1).Value);
    Console.WriteLine(expression2 + " Evaluates to: " + EvaluateBooleanExpression(expression2).Value);
    Console.WriteLine(expression3 + " Evaluates to: " + EvaluateBooleanExpression(expression3).Value);
}
```

Prints:

```
4 == 5 || 3 == 6 || 2 == 1 Evaluates to: False
4 == 4 && 5 == 5 && 7 == 7 Evaluates to: True
4 == 4 || 5 == 5 && 3 == 7 Evaluates to: True
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer,this code was good,but has sum bugs,for example the result of "4 == 4 && 3 == 6" expression  should be False but this code returns True,I change the code a little,it seems it works correctly:

Comment: @MaryamBahramfar I fixed the minor bugs. The expression for "&&" was used as "||".  Also one new condition in the evaluation. Everything should be fine now. You can now mark this as an answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Good, It works fine,it was helpful for me